# Installing ng-bootstrap

Tags: node.js, angular, npm

I am trying to install the `ng-bootstrap` package in my app.

I have updated all of my npm packages using `npm i` as well as updating the `@angular/core` and `@angular/cli` modules to the latest version.

However, when I try the command `npm install --save @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap`, I get the following dependency error:

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: development-toolbox@0.0.0
npm ERR! Found: @angular/core@13.3.0
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/core
npm ERR!   peer @angular/core@"13.3.0" from @angular/animations@13.3.0
npm ERR!   node_modules/@angular/animations
npm ERR!     peerOptional @angular/animations@"13.3.0" from @angular/platform-browser@13.3.0
npm ERR!     node_modules/@angular/platform-browser
npm ERR!       peer @angular/platform-browser@"13.3.0" from @angular/forms@13.3.0
npm ERR!       node_modules/@angular/forms
npm ERR!         @angular/forms@"~13.3.0" from the root project
npm ERR!       3 more (@angular/platform-browser-dynamic, @angular/router, the root project)
npm ERR!     @angular/animations@"~13.3.0" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer @angular/core@"13.3.0" from @angular/common@13.3.0
npm ERR!   node_modules/@angular/common
npm ERR!     peer @angular/common@"13.3.0" from @angular/forms@13.3.0
npm ERR!     node_modules/@angular/forms
npm ERR!       @angular/forms@"~13.3.0" from the root project
npm ERR!     peer @angular/common@"13.3.0" from @angular/platform-browser@13.3.0
npm ERR!     node_modules/@angular/platform-browser
npm ERR!       peer @angular/platform-browser@"13.3.0" from @angular/forms@13.3.0
npm ERR!       node_modules/@angular/forms
npm ERR!         @angular/forms@"~13.3.0" from the root project
npm ERR!       3 more (@angular/platform-browser-dynamic, @angular/router, the root project)
npm ERR!     3 more (@angular/platform-browser-dynamic, @angular/router, the root project)
npm ERR!   5 more (@angular/forms, @angular/platform-browser, ...)
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@"*" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: @angular/core@13.3.9
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/core
npm ERR!   peer @angular/core@"13.3.9" from @angular/forms@13.3.9
npm ERR!   node_modules/@angular/forms
npm ERR!     @angular/forms@"~13.3.0" from the root project
npm ERR!     peer @angular/forms@"^13.0.0" from @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@12.1.2
npm ERR!     node_modules/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap
npm ERR!       @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@"*" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! See D:\Users\[user]\AppData\Local\npm-cache\eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     D:\Users\[User]\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-05-25T19_32_11_969Z-debug-0.log
```

How do I interpret this message and solve the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so I found a solution.

1. Run an `npm update` to update all your node packages
2. Verify the version of angular with `ng --version`. As of the date of publication of this response, my version is:

```
Angular CLI: 13.3.7
Node: 16.13.1
Package Manager: npm 8.6.0
OS: win32 x64
Angular: 13.3.10
@angular-devkit/schematics      13.3.7
@angular/cli                    13.3.7
@schematics/angular             13.3.7
rxjs                            7.5.5
typescript                      4.6.4
```

4. Delete your `node_modules` folder.
5. Open `package.json` and make sure that the `devDependencies` match those of the installed angular cli
6. Run `npm i`
7. Install ng-boostrap: `ng add @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap`

Lastly you will need to install the [Popper](https://popper.js.org/) dependency if you count on installing the latest version (12.0.0 or above) of ng-bootstrap.

You can find more information on compatibility among the different versions of ng-bootstrap and the Angular CLI on the [ng-bootstrap website](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/getting-started).

Answer (score 0):

From the official page, the recommended command is:

```
// Installation for Angular CLI
ng add @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap
```

Try that instead of `npm install`

Comment: Yes, I tried doing that but I continue receiving the same error. In addition, the terminal also informs me that it is using npm as the package manager to install it.
`ℹ Using package manager: npm
✔ Found compatible package version: @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@12.1.2.
✔ Package information loaded.

The package @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@12.1.2 will be installed and executed.
Would you like to proceed? Yes
`
After I select yes, then I receive the same identical error.

Answer (score 0):

I always prefer to use the CDN instead of adding another package. I don't really know if it is the best way to do it, but for me it is okay.

Inside your main `index.html` file, in the `head` tag:

```
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

And at the end of the body:

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
```